# Google MAP API key asking to Enable business account

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I am stuck at generating API key for google map but somehow I came to know Google has just changed policies for APIKEY. Can't I get the API key for free use because it's showing me to enable business account?
[image]

Comment: You should accept the answer if you think it solved your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since July 16, 2018, the Google Maps API does not allow freemium without creating a business profile, including the requirement of a credit card for billing.

From there, you will be able to use the old 2,5k free queries per day, but at the moment you cross that line, you will pay for the service.

You can see that in the documentation for old and new users in "View Documentation": https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?apis=maps